# SegmentControllerer First segment should always been selected when i start the application in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I am using a segment control.

in that there are three segments..segment 1,segment 2,segment 3..

My problem..

when I start the application..

I want that the first segment should always selected..

Suggestion please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it...!!!

In viewWillAppear i put the below code...

```
switch (selectedTag){

    case 0:
        segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
        break;
    case 1:
        segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
        break;
    case 2: 
        segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 2;
        break;
    default:    
        segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
}
[super viewWillAppear:animated];  
[self.myTableVies reloadData];
```

Answer (score 1):

`segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;` somewhere in your startup code.

Comment: yeah...I did that before...but. when I put it in the viewWillAppear that is working..but I dont want that ...I only want that when I start the application first segment should be selected..Not every time

Comment: when I put it in the viewWillAppear that is working..but I dont want that ...I did put it in the viewDidload..but its not working there

Comment: Is it part of your first view that is displayed on screen? You could add it to your viewController as a property and then in applicationDidFinishLaunching you can set this property.

Comment: don't have any code for you. That's just what I'd do. So in your RootViewController add a property @property (nonatomic, retain) NSInteger segmentedIndex;. Then synthesize it and override the setter in your implementation. -(void)setSegmentedIndex:(NSInteger)index and in that method call segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = index;